# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wagtail'

Tags: python-3.x, django, wagtail

I am using wagtail with Django, so far the installation has been succesful.Django is runing and Wagtail too when I go the admin url.
[image]
[image]

but I can't login as an admin cause I can't createsuper with the command **python manage.py createsuperuser**.It displays

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wagtail'
```

I am using python 3.7,any help will be appreciated

Comment: Are you running `python manage.py createsuperuser` in a new console tab / window while the server is running? It may be that you haven't activated your virtual environment in the new window.

Comment: I see `(env)` on your screenshot, double check if you have wagtail installed `pip freeze`

Answer (score 0):

what version of wagtail are you using? sometimes, when your code has no bug, try downgrading the python version to see if it works.

Comment: **wagtail 2.9.3**

Answer (score 0):

SO The problem was,I installed wagtail before creating my virtual environment and activate it. what I did is i check if wagtail was in the site-packages of my virtual environment
`pip freeze`
Then after realizing that it was not there, I installed wagtail again in my virtual environment(site-packages folder) with the command `pip install wagtail`